# How to use the simple HttpGET-CRUD-NodeJS example?

Tags: node.js, azure-functions

Given I just use the default template that was generated:

```
module.exports = function (context, req, intable) {
    context.log("Retrieved records:", intable);
    context.res = {
        status: 200,
        body: intable
    };
    context.done();
};
```

and the following json file:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "authLevel": "function"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "inTable",
      "tableName": "person",
      "connection": "serverlessexamplestorage_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in",
      "take": "100"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

What do I do in order to call the function successfully?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The portal "Run" button works by sending a POST request to your function. However, that template specifies `methods: [ "get" ]` restricting the Function to only support GET requests (hence the 405 "Method not allowed" error).

You can use a client like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or whatever your favorite client is to send a GET request, and the function will run successfully. Alternatively you could also allow the function to accept POST requests by adding "post" to the methods array (`methods: [ "get", "post" ]`) and you'd be able to invoke it from the portal.

I agree that this is somewhat confusing. The issue is that the Functions portal isn't a full blown HTTP client, so it doesn't allow you to specify http method, headers, etc. We have an [open issue](https://github.com/projectkudu/AzureFunctionsPortal/issues/611) in our repo to improve that. To what degree we'll build out a fully featured HTTP client in the portal is TBD, so for now your best option is to use an external client for all but simple cases.

Comment: That makes sense. I was using Postman too, but I forgot to change the drop down to GET when I run the HttpPost example with POST. This is a separate question, is there a way to dynamically modify the `json` config file to say change the `TableName` prior for the `inTable` getting populated?